# Why is this Ruby on Rails program giving me a syntax error?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

RoR beginner here. I am trying to make an instagram-like feed on one of my views. I am running this code to do so:

```
<h2>University Student Food Recipes</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <% @images.each do |image| %>
            <%= image_tag image.image, class: "img img-fluid" %>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @images = Image.all
    end
end
```

However, the page gives me a syntax error saying:

```
ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in PagesController#home

Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check <h2>University Student Food Recipes</h2> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-8"> <% @images.each do |image| %> <%= image_tag image.image, class: "img img-fluid" %> </div> </div> </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the `<% ... %>` tags are used to run Ruby code in your `.erb.html` templates. Above, you've just forgot to close the block with an `end` keyword. It should be:

```
    <div class="col-8">
        <% @images.each do |image| %>
            <%= image_tag image.image, class: "img img-fluid" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

See: https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/